# How can i receive telegram message in C# using Telegram API

Tags: c#, telegram

I am using [this telegram C# library](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) .I am able to send the messages but Couldn't find a way how to receive messages in this library. Please assist me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SochiX I am using your library. Could you please help me how can i receive telegram messages using this library.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that library only supports some functionality, receiving is probably not supported as it isn't mentioned in the documentation and there is no test for it.

Answer (score 1):

I have this functionality(and many other) implemented in my [fork](https://github.com/steavy29/Telegram.Net)

You need to create `TelegramClient` instance, subscribe to `UpdateMessage` event and call `Start` method.

```
var client = new TelegramClient(null/*sessionStore*/, apiId, apiHash);
client.UpdateMessage += (sender, updates) =>
{
      switch (updates.constructor)
      {
          case Constructor.UpdatesTooLong: { break; }
          case Constructor.UpdateShortMessage: { break; }
          case Constructor.UpdateShortChatMessage: { break; }
          case Constructor.UpdateShort: { break; }
          case Constructor.UpdatesCombined: { break; }
          case Constructor.Updates: { break; }
      }
};
await client.Start();
```

For list of possible Update object constructors see [this](https://core.telegram.org/type/Updates)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this api you have mentioned, but if receiving messages is not supported in that one, I suggest using [this one](https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot)

I been using it since almost 1 year ago, I made a Fun bot for my university group where people can teach the bot what to answer to certain messages it receives.
The usage is pretty simple and it have an example you can [learn from](https://github.com/MrRoundRobin/telegram.bot.examples/blob/master/Telegram.Bot.Examples.Echo/Program.cs).

You can also check [my bot](https://telegram.me/AlaftarinBot) here and see its functionality.